# Rounding a float to an int in haskell

Tags: haskell, casting, type-conversion

Problem 3 of Project Euler says: The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

I made a lazy list of primes, then I do a takeWhile they are less than the square root of 600851475143, and test each prime to see if it is a factor.

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = sieve [2..]
    where
        sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
primeFactors :: Integer -> Integer
primeFactors x = last $ filter (\y -> x `mod` y == 0) $ takeWhile (< floor (sqrt x)) $ primes
```

However, I get an error with `(< floor (sqrt x))`:

```
projecteuler.hs:34:70:
    No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of `floor'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Integer)
    In the second argument of `(<)', namely `floor (sqrt x)'
    In the first argument of `takeWhile', namely `(< floor (sqrt x))'
    In the expression: takeWhile (< floor (sqrt x))

projecteuler.hs:34:77:
    No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of `sqrt'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Integer)
    In the first argument of `floor', namely `(sqrt x)'
    In the second argument of `(<)', namely `floor (sqrt x)'
    In the first argument of `takeWhile', namely `(< floor (sqrt x))'
```

This is weird: :t `floor` gives me `(Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b`, which means that this floor should be returning a integer.  How can I add an instance declaration (or do whatever is necessary to fix this?)

Also, any suggestions on code optimization are greatly appreciated :)

Edit: this has been solved, and now I am cleaning it up.  I've encapsulated everything inside of the main function, so it looks like this:

```
p003primeFactors :: Integer -> [Integer]
p003primeFactors x = filter (\y -> x `mod` y == 0) $ takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= x) $ primes
    where
        primes :: [Integer]
        primes = sieve [2..]
            where
                sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

Is this the best way to create namespaces for functions like this?

Comment: You can optimise your sieve by doing: ``primes = 2 : sieve [3,5..]``. Alternatively, you can implement something like [this](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf). It should speed up you code by a significant amount. You can also use [``Math.NumberTheory.Prime``](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellForMaths-0.4.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Prime.html) to save youself some work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is the second error. (The first is just a consequence.) The `x` is an `Integer`, so you cannot call `sqrt` on it, because that requires a `Floating` instance.

Try:

```
takeWhile (< floor (sqrt (fromIntegral x)))
```

This will convert `x` from an integer to a floating point number so that `sqrt` can operate on it.

Comment: Or use `(\p -> p^2 <= x)` in place of `(< floor (sqrt x))`. No need for `sqrt`, really.

Comment: Yes, agreed. In this particular case, there are better options.